# Выдает ошибку когда присваиваю id в файле .kv с помощью on_parent

Tags: python, kivy

Что бы я не делал, постоянно выдает ошибку:

```
4:    BoxLayout:     
5:    orientation: "vertical"
6:    on_parent: self.add_widget(Button(text="2", id="2"))
 ...
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Файл `.py`:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
        
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
        
Builder.load_file("stackoverflow.kv")
    
    
    
class Main(Screen):
    pass
        
        
sm=ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Main(name="main"))
    
class SaveApp(App): 
    def build(self):        
        return sm
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SaveApp().run()
```

Файл `.kv`:

```
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button
<Main>:
            
    BoxLayout:     
        orientation: "vertical"
        on_parent: self.add_widget(Button(text="2", id="2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Как видно из вывода, проблема связана со строкой `on_parent`:

А именно `self.add_widget(Button(text="2", id="2"))` в твоём файле `.kv`.

Событие `on_parent` запускается каждый раз, когда виджет добавляется как дочерний элемент другого виджета, и функция, указанная в `on_parent`, вызывается с родительским виджетом в качестве единственного аргумента.
Однако метод `add_widget()` принимает только один аргумент, который является виджетом, добавляемым в качестве дочернего элемента.
Следовательно, ты получаешь ошибку `TypeError`, потому что метод `add_widget()` получает два аргумента вместо одного.

Чтобы устранить эту проблему, ты можешь использовать событие `on_parent` для вызова функции, которая добавляет кнопку в качестве дочернего элемента `BoxLayout`.

**Вот то, что тебе нужно изменить:**

В твоём файле `.kv` замени строку

```python
on_parent: self.add_widget(Button(text="2", id="2"))
```

на:

```python
on_parent: root.add_button()
```

Это вызовет метод `add_button()` основного виджета (который является корневым виджетом твоего экрана), который нужно будет определить (код ниже).

В код Python добавь следующий метод в основной класс:

```python
class Main(Screen):
     def add_button(self):
         self.add_widget(Button(text="2", id="2"))
```

Этот метод просто добавляет кнопку с текстом "2" и идентификатором "2" в качестве дочернего элемента `BoxLayout` основного виджета.

С этими изменениями твой код должен работать без каких-либо ошибок.

Comment: Все равно выходит та же ошибка

Comment: Возможно, в вашем коде есть другая проблема.

1. Убедитесь, что ваши файлы .py и .kv имеют правильные имена и находятся в одном каталоге

2. Убедитесь, что ваш оператор Builder.load_file("stackoverflow.kv") загружает правильный файл .kv

3. Убедитесь, что вы используете правильную версию Kivy

4. Попробуйте удалить аргумент id="2" из виджета Button. Этот аргумент не является необходимым и может вызывать проблемы.

Если ни один из этих шагов не решает проблему, предоставьте дополнительную информацию о сообщении об ошибке и любые другие важные сведения, чтобы я мог помочь вам лучше.

Comment: В коде ошибка заключается исключительно в аргументе id, как только я его убираю, код работает корректно.